# Incremental load from DB2 to Snowflake

Tags: db2, airflow, etl

My source table is in DB2, and target table in snowflake, and I use airflow to orchestrate the ETL, how do I do the incremental load?

I could only find methods to do incremental load between 2 tables both in snowflakes. thanks

Comment: How are you doing your basic ETL? Bear in mind that if you are looking for recommendations for ETL tools then this would be out of scope for this forum

Comment: @NickW I use Amazon managed Apache airflow, the current dag is to truncate the target table and reload all the data, but I want to do incremental load. I extract the data from source table in db2 and convert it into a panda frame before loading into sf table.

Comment: So extract the incremental changes from your source system and merge them into your target table